# Закодированые файлы. Возможно ли их раскодировать?

Tags: php

Скачал файл с расширением .php
Хотел посмотреть код, а там...

```
<?php $_0OO=__FILE__;$_O0O=6;$_OOO=15066;  eval(base64_decode("JF8wMDBPPUFycmF5KCk7Zm9yICgkXzBPT089OTc7JF8wT09PPDEyMzskXzBPT08rKykgJF8wMDBPW109Y2hyKCRfME9PTyk7Zm9yICgkXzBPT089NjU7JF8wT09PPDkxOyRfME9PTysrKSAkXzAwME9bXT1jaHIoJF8wT09PKTskXzAwMDA9aW1wbG9kZSgiIiwkXz.....h1OVOSogm7Ub==*/
/*
Encrypted by CNCrypto http://www.hhhhhhh/en/cncrypto/

*/?>
```

Возможно ли декодировать код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo htmlspecialchars(base64_decode("JF8wMDBPPUFycm..."));`